# Variable not changing in IF statement

Tags: javascript

I am a JS beginner, so I am having some trouble with this one.

I have a variable called morale, and it updates based on some math. This is working just fine. What I am now trying to do is basically log the highest number morale has ever been, that way I can do some maths based off max morale. The max_morale is not changing at all, even though the morale is. I figured this code should work fine, but it is not. I do have `<span id="max_morale">0</span>` in my HTML. Please help!

```
var morale = 0;
var max_morale = 0;
var money = 0;

function increment(number){
    money = money + number;
    document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = addCommas(money);
};


function moraleCalc(){
    morale = Math.floor(money * 0.0009)+"%";
    document.getElementById('morale').innerHTML = morale;
        if(morale > max_morale){
        max_morale = morale;
        document.getElementById('max_morale').innerHTML = max_morale;
    };    
};

window.setInterval(function(){
    moraleCalc();
}, 1000);
```

Comment: I don't see `money` anywhere?

Comment: Updated code, it didn't seem necessary. Sorry about that.

Comment: Don't know why people downvote, this seems like a valid question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

morale is a string value because you append "%", not a number.

You are comparing the string to an Integer.

Comment: Right, so append your '%' when you do the assignment to innerHTML.

Comment: Yep it's working now. Will accept this as an answer once the site allows me.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem arises when you calculate morale. By adding the `+"%` to the calculation, you change morale from a number type to a string. After that your comparison becomes unpredictable.

Better leave morale a number, and change to string when assigning to innerHTML

```
morale = Math.floor(money * 0.0009);
....
document.getElementById('max_morale') =
```

max_morale.toString() + '%';